# What's the correct request to get the geometry from Overpass reverse geocoding with GeoJSON?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I found a query results a list of all the boundaries contains a point.

```
[out:json];
is_in(28.2,-16.6);
out;
```

But it lacks the shape information, preferably in GeoJSON format.

What should be included in this query to request such information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_in` only produces areas, which need to be turned into a first-class citizen via `rel(pivot)` in case of relations:

```
[out:json];
is_in(28.2,-16.6);
rel(pivot);
out geom;
```

Further restricting `rel(pivot)` to the kind of relations you're interested in is highly recommended to reduce load and data volume.

Besides, Overpass API does not support GeoJSON format. You need an external library/tool to convert OSM to GeoJSON, such as [osmtogeojson](https://github.com/tyrasd/osmtogeojson), which is also used in overpass turbo.

Comment: thanks, but now it returns only coordinates and attributes and meta information is missing in the returned JSON. How to include attributes and meta data in this query?

Comment: Looks like I'm wrong. In the raw data all the properties are there.

Comment: For meta data you can use `out geom meta;` instead. There's also the option to return OSM XML format: `is_in(28.2,-16.6);rel(pivot);(._;>;);out meta;`